# How can I edit unusual clipboard content?

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard, text-editing

I'd like to edit application specific clipboard content, with an application specific format. There are clipboard managers that let me edit the plain text content, but I'd like to access clipboard content that applications use for internal cut and paste.

An example would be when you copy something from a web page in Firefox. When you look at the different formats in a clipboard viewer, there are three or so formats starting with "moz", with content that is not plain text.

I'd like to edit that content before pasting it back into Firefox. Can this be done?

Comment: Why not just do necessary edits in the source application?

Comment: Because I have no access to the source of the source application. I want to edit any clipboard content, wherever it came from.